# IE ajax sending utf8 chars as?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, utf-8

take `$("#"+id).val()` in consideration

```
var field = document.getElementById( id );
/* ... */
if( field.value != "" )
    var jqxhr = $.get( "/user/ajaxtag/tag/" + $("#"+id).val(), function( data ) {
        suggestionText = data;
        //does something which i thing is non of problem's business
        var arr = getListItems( field.value );
        if ( field.value.length > 0 ){
            createList( arr );
        } else {
            clearList();
        };
        // end of non of business
    });
```

when using english in the input box which triggers this piece of code on change, the ajax request is responded successfully, but when using persian like "س" IE sends this

```
GET /user/ajaxtag/tag/??_=1338567574102 HTTP/1.1\r\n
```

(i got this information on wireshark) and replaces the utf8 chars with ?, the problem doesn't occur when i use firefox, only in ie (not a surprise ha?) i have this line in the header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

in another question on stackoverflow.com it was suggested to change php.ini, but i am on a shared host and dont have access to the file.

i did `alert( $( "#" + id ).val() )` and the alerted thing was not ? was the input char.. like س

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode parameter names and values with encodeURIComponent() function.

or to make it RFC3986 compliant you can use this function:

```
/** 
 * encodeURIComponent() function is not 100% compatible with
 * RFC3986 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html
 */
function encodeRFC3986(value) {
  return encodeURIComponent(value)
    .replace(/!/g,  "%21")
    .replace(/\*/g, "%2A")
    .replace(/\(/g, "%28")
    .replace(/\)/g, "%29")
    .replace(/'/g,  "%27");
}
```

Comment: yes it should be replaced like `var jqxhr = $.get("/user/ajaxtag/tag/"+encodeURIComponent($("#"+id).val()), function(data) {...` thank you ...

Comment: why does it matter to be RFC3986 compliant?

Comment: some platforms require strings to be encoded in RFC3986 format, encodeURIComponent() is not 100% compatible, i posted this for answer completeness

Comment: it always makes me feel safe when something works in IE and other major borwsers (usually chrome and firefox) , having no courage to make my code better, BTW it's important to have standards in mind.  thank you..